# Airflow starts two DAG runs when turned on for the first time

Tags: airflow

When I boot up the Airflow webserver and scheduler for the first time on Oct 25th at around 17:23, and turn on my DAG, I can see that it kicks off two runs for Oct 23rd and Oct 24th:

```
RUN 1 -> 10-23T17:23
RUN 2 -> 10-24T17:23
```

Here's my DAG configuration:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': '2019-01-01',
    'retries': 0,
}
dag = DAG(
    'my_script',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
    catchup=False,
)
```

Since it's past the `start_date + schedule_interval` and I have set `catchup=False`, I would expect it to kick off a single DAG run immediately, however I would not expect it to run two.

- Why are two DAG runs being executed?
- How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure but this is my best guess -

In short answer, could be it is how airflow is built and workaround would be to modify your `start_date` to be yesterday.

TL;DR

I agree that kicks off 1 dag for 10-24 when you turned on would sound more natural.

However, according to your dag runs, RUN 1 is 10-23.
This suggests to me that initializing of the first run is not correct and I have looked into the scheduler code.

And I have a doubt on this line.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/68b8ec5f415795e4fa4ff7df35a3e75c712a7bad/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py#L603

This is inside a function that create a dag run and setting the start date of the run.

```
# The logic is that we move start_date up until
# one period before, so that timezone.utcnow() is AFTER
# the period end, and the job can be created...
now = timezone.utcnow()

# This returns current time + schedule_interval. In your example, this will be tomorrow.
next_start = dag.following_schedule(now)

# This returns current time - schedule_interval. In your example, this will be yesterday.
last_start = dag.previous_schedule(now)

# tomorrow <= today should return False 
if next_start <= now:
    new_start = last_start
else:
    # and this will return last_start - schedule_interval which means 2 days ago.  
    # wondering if this is intended to be dag.previous_schedule(next_start)???
    new_start = dag.previous_schedule(last_start)
```

Comment: You're right, if I use yesterday (in my case 2019-10-24) as the `start_date` then only one DAG gets executed

Comment: Cool!  If you think this is worth bringing up to airflow, please feel free. didn't want to steal your findings ;)

Comment: +1, yes pls. I'm facing the same issues and would like to understand the ration of why it goes 2 cycles back instead just one (the latest!) *execution_date* back

Comment: I've encountered the same problem of re-enabling a paused DAG (with catchup=False), actually created 2 DAG runs, instead of 1

Comment: @Emma and AlexG, could we report and/or submit a PR to the Airflow team?

Comment: I've been facing this issue too. Can someone link the PR?