# Catchup flag in in Airflow dag is not working properly

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

Steps (today is January 7 of 2020):

1) Put the following dag in Airflow dir:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

dag = DAG(dag_id='example_dag', start_date=datetime(2020, 1, 1), catchup=False)

t1 = BashOperator(task_id='bash_task', bash_command='echo Hola!', dag=dag)
```

Please note the catch up flag preventing Airflow to schedule on expired dates.

2) Start a fresh Airflow instance

3) Turn the dag on in the UI

4) Execution:

[image]

I really don't understand why these dags on expired dates (January 5 and January 6) are being scheduled and executed if I am using the catch up flag and deploying on January 7. Any advice? Thanks!

Update: without catch up flag I got:

[image]

So:

1) catch up flag is being taken into account

2) it seems to have a bug or it is not well configured because when it is set to False Airflow is still scheduling on expired dates (January 5 and January 6).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58563313/2956135

Comment: But this is a bug, right? The catch up flag is preventing Airflow to "backfill" previous jobs and jobs from January 5 and January 6 are definitely old in January 7.

Comment: Jan 5 is "seems" wrong but Jan 6 is correct for Jan7. Airflow triggers run after `schedule_interval` is covered.  and by default schedule_interval is one day.   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61740904/5691525, Airflow  Scheduler creates a DAG Run for the most current instance of the DAG interval series when `catchup=False` but there was a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1156) (when using a timedelta object for `schedule_interval`) that created 2 DagRuns.

For your case, you didn't pass the `schedule_interval` field to your DAG because of which it takes the default. The default is `timedelta(days=1)` (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/3ad4f96bae78f16a2240567f65831ca269672d7b/airflow/models/dag.py#L212) which is why there were 2 DagRuns created.

This will be fixed in Airflow 1.10.11 and has been fixed for the Master with [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/8776) PR.